# Load Trained SVM – Emgu CV

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I am somewhat new to SVMs and object recognition, and am currently attempting to train an SVM using Emgu CV 3.0, save it to a file, and then load it (for use in HOGDescriptor.SetSVMDetector).

However, among other problems, I cannot find a way to load the SVM after I have saved it.

So far, my code basically does the following:

```
SVM myFirstSVM = new SVM();

// do some stuff, set some parameters...

myFirstSVM.Train(someParameters);

myFirstSVM.Save("filePath");
```

From here, the problem lies with **reloading** the SVM after being saved. I have checked several help topics and pages, and the only related things I could find pertained to OpenCV, which used the following method:

```
SVM mySecondSVM;

mySecondSVM.load("filePath");
```

However, I could find no method ".load()" in Emgu 3.0, although it appeared to be present in previous versions.  Is there an equivalent of this OpenCV method in Emgu 3.0?  I would assume there is, and I am sure it is fairly simple, but I cannot for the life of me find it.

Answer (score 2):

For EmguCV 3.0.0, the `Save/Load` functionality doesn't seem to be supported (`Load` doesn't exist), you could use `Write/Read` instead.

A function to save an SVM model:

```
public static void SaveSVMToFile(SVM model, String path) {
    if (File.Exists(path)) File.Delete(path);
    FileStorage fs = new FileStorage(path, FileStorage.Mode.Write);
    model.Write(fs);
    fs.ReleaseAndGetString();
}
```

A function to load the SVM model provided the correct path:

```
public static SVM LoadSVMFromFile(String path) {
    SVM svm = new SVM();
    FileStorage fs = new FileStorage(path, FileStorage.Mode.Read);
    svm.Read(fs.GetRoot());
    fs.ReleaseAndGetString();
    return svm;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have saved and read the SVM model using the specified functions. But I am working with 3.1.0 version and hope it works for you as well:

I have saved the model in an XML file because the read function works on xml file as far as I know:

```
Emgu.CV.ML.SVM model = new Emgu.CV.ML.SVM();
model.SetKernel(Emgu.CV.ML.SVM.SvmKernelType.Linear);
model.Type = Emgu.CV.ML.SVM.SvmType.CSvc;
model.C = 1;
model.TermCriteria = new MCvTermCriteria(100, 0.00001);
bool trained = model.TrainAuto(my_trainData, 5);
model.Save("SVM_Model.xml");
```

and I read the model as follows:

```
Emgu.CV.ML.SVM model_loaded = new Emgu.CV.ML.SVM();
FileStorage fsr = new FileStorage("SVM_Model.xml", FileStorage.Mode.Read);
model_loaded.Read(fsr.GetFirstTopLevelNode());
```

and it works correctly.
I hope it works for you so.

Answer (score 0):

For EmguCV 1.5.0:

> [Load Method (fileName)](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/e88519e0-825d-0df5-9b4a-bdd0043bcd49.htm):
>
> Inherited from [StatModel](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/8d64fda7-97c5-2558-fc4d-67edc53e511d.htm)
>
> *Load the statistic model from file*
>
> > **fileName (String)**
> >
> > *The file to load the model from*

For EmguCV 3.0+:

`Load()` is not available, as you can see in the source code: https://sourceforge.net/p/emgucv/code/ci/master/tree/Emgu.CV.ML/StatModel.cs

Comment: I did.  There is no extension method ".Load("file path")" in Emgu for SVM objects.

Comment: @JohiasburgFrowell Are you sure? This information comes from its documentation: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/5c8147fa-4959-df3f-4d73-f1c549c06738.htm

Comment: I am using version 3.0, the documentation you referenced is severely outdated.  3.0 documentation can be found at http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/5c8147fa-4959-df3f-4d73-f1c549c06738.htm

Comment: @JohiasburgFrowell that's interesting... on source code the `Load()` method was commented... perhaps a bug?